# A Strange Result Of Divisibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, arithmetic, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

> Let $p$ be a positive integer. Let $H$ be a subgroup of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$.
>
> Let $a>1$ be an integer such that $a \in H$ (more precisely, the residue class of $a$ modulo $p$ belongs to $H$). Let $c$ be an integer such that $-pc \equiv 1 \mod a$.
>
> Prove that $(a-1) \mid \sum \limits_{h\in H} p(hc \mod a)$.

Here, $m \mod n$ means the remainder of $m$ modulo $n$.

***Source*** : les dattes à Dattier

Comment: I identifie $\mathbb Z/ p\mathbb Z$ to the number set {0,1, 2,...,p-1}

Comment: $a \mod p$ is the remainder of the euclidean division of a by p.

Comment: What do you mean by $-h/p\mod{a}$? Is that a division and modulo? Why would $h/p$ be always integer? Or why would $p$ be invertible in $\mod{a}$ if we are talking about division modulo? The right side is very unclear to me.

Comment: pgcd(p,a)=1 because $a\in(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$ so p is invertible mod a, and $(1/p \mod a)\in \{1,..,a-1\}$

Comment: No, the sum is in $(\mathbb N,+)$ not in $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$

Comment: $(h\mod a)\in\mathbb N\cap [0,a−1]$

Comment: For subgroups $H$ that contain $p-1$, this is because $H$ can be partitioned into disjoint sets of the form $\{h,p-h\}$, and $(p-h)c\bmod a = a - 1 - (hc\bmod a)$, so the sum of the two mods is $a-1$. But in general, $H$ need not contain $p-1$.

Comment: But in general, H need not contain p−1 : yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- $
  \newcommand{\mymod}{\mathop{\mathtt{mod}}}
  $For clarity, we will write $\mymod(k,n)$ in place of $k\text{ mod }n$ to denote the remainder of $k$ modulo $n$ in the set of representatives $\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$. For future use, note that $\mymod(\cdot,\cdot)$ takes the form

  $$ \mymod(k,n) = k - n\lfloor k/n\rfloor $$

  for each positive integer $n$.
- We identify the elements of $H \subseteq \left(\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z\right)^{\ast}$ with their representatives in the set $\left\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\right\}$. Since $a \in H$, the mapping $h \mapsto \mathtt{mod}(ah,p) $ is a permutation on $H$.
- Now let $S$ denote the sum in question. Then we can write

  \begin{align*}
  S
  &= \sum_{h \in H} p \mymod(hc, a) \tag{by def. of $S$} \\
  &= \sum_{h \in H} p \mymod(c \mymod(ah, p), a) \tag{by permutation} \\
  &= \sum_{h \in H} p \mymod(c( ah - p\lfloor ah/p\rfloor), a) \tag{by def. of $\mymod$} \\
  &= \sum_{h \in H} p \mymod(\lfloor ah/p\rfloor, a).
  \end{align*}

  Here, the last step follows from

  $$c(ah-p\lfloor ah/p\rfloor) \equiv \lfloor ah/p \rfloor \pmod{a},$$

  which itself is an easy consequence of the assumption $-cp \equiv 1 \pmod{a}$.
- Since $a > 1$ and $0 < h/p < 1$, it follows that $\mymod(\lfloor ah/p\rfloor, a) = \lfloor ah/p\rfloor$. Plugging this back,

  \begin{align*}
  S
  &= \sum_{h \in H} p \lfloor ah/p\rfloor \\
  &= \sum_{h \in H} ah - \sum_{h \in H} \mymod(ah, p) \tag{by def. of $\mymod$} \\
  &= \sum_{h \in H} ah - \sum_{h \in H} h \tag{by permutation} \\
  &= (a-1)\sum_{h\in H} h.
  \end{align*}

  Therefore the claim follows.

Comment: Bravo, It's impressive for me

Comment: Good for being a "weak point"! :)

Comment: I don't understand @mickep

Comment: In another (linked) question Sanghul Lee mentioned that his/her weak point was algebra.

Comment: My strong points seems weaker than its weak points... lol

Comment: @mickep, Haha, thank you. To be honest, this idea was a pure luck that is far above my algebra skills. And you may call me 'he' as both the gravatar and my name suggest. (Indeed, it is a typical masculine name in my country.)

Comment: @Sangchul Lee : Every time I find a solution, it's as if I win at loto, I see the winning draw formed in my head, without I do anything else but want to find the solution. Thanks My God.